# Is it ok to begin a sentence with "Currently being" in order to say something like "Siendo actualmente"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage

I'm kind of translating my CV into English, but I got stuck in the following part:

During the second year of my IT degree, three years ago, I started getting involved in several projects, working on the analysis and design of architectures as solutions to different use cases, as well as on databases management. Currently being web and mobile, the areas in which I have achieved greater professional development.

edit: 
what I'm trying to express is that web and mobile development, are the areas in which I have achieved a greater professional improvement. Considering that in the previous sentence, I'm referring to the same topic, but talking about the past. 
From a grammatical point of view, I'm not sure if 'Currently being', 'Actually being' or something like that is a correct way of starting a sentence and switching to present tense, neither if it's commonly used.

Hope I made myself clear. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your post to explain the intended meaning. What are you trying to express?

Comment: Just replace that with "My current role as a web and mobile developer..."

Comment: @NikosHidalgo thanks! But the solution you proposed makes me think about a whole new sentence, I would like something that is more connected with what I was talking before. 
I'll consider it anyways!

Answer (score 1):

> Currently being web and mobile development, the areas in which I have achieved greater professional development.

This sentence doesn't work very well, you're inverting the beginning and end of the sentence and we usually avoid that for clarity.

The best alternative would be (I would consider changing the first 'development' so it doesn't get too repetitive):

> The areas in which I have achieved greater professional development are web and mobile development.

You can say "Currently working on web...", but it wouldn't fit with the meaning you're trying to convey.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I get that "Currently being" doesn't sound as good as it sounds its Spanish translation, so I will consider your advice and rethink that expression, although I still think that your suggestion doesn't fit with the previous sentence that well.
Regarding to the development repetition, I just decided to remove the first one.